# What is meaning in simple word of this phrase?

Tags: vocabulary

“Bugger off smart arse!”

It appears in a technical article on link
https://www.csimn.com/CSI_pages/PIDforDummies.html

Answer (score 2):

"Bugger off" is a rude British term for "go away and stop bothering me."

"Smart arse" is a rude British term (equivalent to the rude American term "smart ass") that means a person who is not being serious.

Comment: A "smart arse" is not someone who is "not being serious"; it is someone who shows off their knowledge or learning, or who is too often sarcastic.

Comment: So is showing off or being sarcastic being serious? Is someone who is being frivolous never accused of being a "smart arse"?

Comment: A smart arse is a particularly annoying kind of person, like a "clever dick". One can be playfully frivolous without annoying people.

Comment: OK. I shall grant "annoying," it was the limiting nature of why someone being annoying that was bothering me.

Answer (score 2):

This can be broken down to two distinct slang elements, both impolite/insulting:

- *"Bugger off"* - Go away
- *"smartarse"* - person who is using their intelligence, seemingly to show off  (see also, *clever clogs*)

This is a reasonable example of a classically British use of swearing.

Comment: Buggery is anal sex. Curiously, in the British scale, "bugger off" is less profane that "f**k off".

Comment: "Bugger off, smartarse" has two allusions to the posterior. Is that a British preoccupation?